# Create light in JAVA using RadialGradientPaint

Tags: java, awt, light, radial-gradients

Im working on a simple game engine using java.
Im want to make some light in the game and I want to use RadialGradientPaint.

Here is my light class

```
package engine.graphics;

import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RadialGradientPaint;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import engine.Main;
import engine.maths.Vector2f;

public class Light 
{
    private Vector2f pos;
    private int radius;

    public Light(Vector2f pos, int radius)
    {
        this.pos = pos;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        Point2D center = new Point2D.Float(pos.x, pos.y);
        float[] dist = {0.9f, 1.0f};
        Color[] color = {new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f), new Color(0, 0, 0, 255)};
        RadialGradientPaint p  = new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius,  dist, color);
        g2d.setPaint(p);
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, .95f));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, Main.WIDTH, Main.HEIGHT);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

The problem that i found is that i cant draw more than one light.
How can i modify my code to make more lights? 
Thank you..

Comment: Can you show us the full light class?

Comment: of course. There isnt something more that render method. Im just initialize position of light and its radius

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I propose you this :

```
package solamda;

 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.Graphics2D;
 import java.awt.Point;
 import java.awt.RadialGradientPaint;
 import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;

 public class Main {
    private static final Color transparency = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.add(new JLabel() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                render(g);
            }
         });

        f.pack();
         f.setVisible(true);
     }

    public static void render(Graphics g) {
         Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
         Point[] lights = { new Point(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2), new Point(0,0),
                new Point(WIDTH / 2+10, HEIGHT / 2), new Point(WIDTH / 2-10, HEIGHT / 2) };
         for (Point center : lights) {
             paintlight(g2d, center);
         }
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    private static void paintlight(Graphics2D g2d, Point center) {
        float[] dist = { 0.2f, 1.0f };
        Color[] color = { Color.white, transparency };
        RadialGradientPaint p = new RadialGradientPaint(center, 10, dist, color);
        g2d.setPaint(p);
        g2d.fillRect(center.x - 20, center.y - 20, 40, 40);

     }
}
```

You don need to fill whole rect just the part where the light is . So from your code i just extract a method where center is a parameter (call paintlight) then in your method render, i can draw as many ligh as i want ; i simply paint a white hallo arround this point and i keep the transparency in the pattern when i paint it

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: you don need to fill all the rect just the part where the lighr is . so from your code i just extract as the thod where center is a parameter a new method (call paintlight) then inn the method render i can draw as many ligh as i want because i plain a white hallo arroun this point and i keep the trans^parency of the background when i did it